# Automatic download of .ics file

Tags: jakarta-ee, icalendar

I have a Java EE application and an option for downloading a calendar (that can be imported in Outlook). What I want to do is to download the calendar automatically every day at a particular time. I want to add this option to prevent logging into an application every day and downloading it manually. Is it possible somehow to set an absolute file system path and call the download action in scheduled time?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side, you'd have to create a scheduled task (in Windows) or a cron job (on Linux) that executes e.g. wget to download your file.

See http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task
and http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm